Computing the ideal of a projective algebraic set of $\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$
I am computing the ideal of the (projective algebraic) set $X_2=\{[1,0,0],[0,1,1]\}$ in $\mathbb{P}^2_\mathbb{C}$.
My approach is computing the ideal of each single point, then taking the intersection of them. Since the ideal of $P=[x_0,y_0,z_0]$ is $I_P=(y_0X-x_0Y,z_0Y-y_0Z,z_0X-x_0Z)$, we get the ideal of $[1,0,0]$ and $[0,1,1]$ is $J_1=(Y,Z)$ and $J_2=(X,Y-Z)$, respectively. Now I can compute
$$I(X_2)=J_1 \cap J_2=(Y,Z) \cap (X,Y-Z).$$
At this point I don't know what to do next. These ideals are not coprime so we cannot use $J_1J_2=J_1 \cap J_2$. One main issue is that $Y-Z$ is not a monomial, so we cannot use the computational technique for monomial ideals, either.
Any intution or approach will be appreciated.

There are algorithms based on Groebner basis calculations to find intersections of ideals of polynomial rings, in case you'd be interested in seeing that.

Let $I=(X), J=(Y-Z)$ and $P=(Y,Z)$. Note that $J\subseteq P$, so $P\cap(I+J)=P\cap I+P\cap J=(XY,XZ)+(Y-Z)=(XY,Y-Z)$.

My intuition goes as follows: The ideal of the set $X_2$ is the set of all those functions vanishing in both these points. Now to find a good set of generators (which is what I presume you mean by "computing" the ideal) means to find as few functions as posssible whose common vanishing locus is exactly $X_2$. Alternatively still: We want the zero sets of all these functions to intersect in the two points of $X_2$.
Usually, this is not too easy, but here we only have two points, which is managable. I claim that they can be realized as an intersection of a conic section $c$ and a line $l$.
For $l$ we take the line connecting the two points, which is given by $Y - Z = 0$ (NOTE: The polynomial $Y - Z$ appears in both ideals that you have written down).
For $c$ I pick any conic section (that does not contain my line given by $l$) vanishing in $X_2$, e.g. $XY = 0$ (NOTE: This is also contained in both your ideals). If you prefer smooth conics, then you can take for example $(Y - Z)^2 - XZ$ (which is a parabola in the coordinate chart $Z = 1$).
You can now verify that the ideal $\langle Y - Z, XY \rangle$ is indeed radical and that its vanishing set is $X_2$.
